A question about CRC
The probability of the undetected errors for an n bit CRC is said to be $1/2^n$. But in practice, CRC also has bit errors in itself. Could I say that a 16 bit CRC reduces to a 13 bit CRC if the BER is 20%?

For a random draw of bits, the probability of undetectable errors is $1/2^n$, but if you have non-random bits - for example, if you have a valid codeword that is divisible by the CRC generator polynomial and have a BER that is not 50% - then the probability changes and is dependent on the codeword size and BER.
For example, suppose the number of user bits is 1 and the CRC remainder is length p and these are detected with BER=20%. The codeword is then length $p+1$, and the only way you get an undetectable error is if all of the bits are in error. Aside from some bug that happened to flip all of the bits, this is less likely than an undetectable error from random draws, since the BER is less than 50%.
Example:  p=3 with BER=0.2
$$
P_{undetectable} = 0.0016 = (1/5)^{p+1} < (1/2)^{p+1} = 0.0625
$$
Of course, this is a trivial case, but the notion is that it is harder to come up with an error polynomial divisible by the CRC generator polynomial than to do a random draw of bits (same code block size) that is divisible by the CRC generator polynomial.

Thank you. In communication systems valid codeword is always sent. Then the probability of undetected errors depends on BER. Do I understand it correctly?

Yes, depends on BER and on codeword size. Even though only valid codewords are sent, there can be cases in practice where the receiver expects a transmission but the transmitter missed the allocation and didn't send anything, or there is a false alarm in detecting a preamble/sync/training-sequence, and the follow-on reception is only noise.


Could I say that a 16 bit CRC reduces to a 13 bit CRC if the BER is 20%?

The OP can say anything that the OP wants to say, but I don't understand the message that the OP is trying to convey to the reader; ymmv.
Minus the various bells and whistles that actual CRC implementations use, a CRC-encoded data transmission consists of $k$ data bits followed by the $r$ CRC bits  (where $r$  can be $8, 12, 16,$ or $32$ depending on which CRC system is in use). The OP is considering $16$-bit CRCs, so let's stick with that. For $16$-bit CRCs, $k$ needs to be smaller than $32,752$ bits, but most CRC systems limit themselves to much smaller values of $k$ (usually less than $2,000$).  The transmitter computes the CRC bits from the $k$ data bits using polynomial division (see this answer of mine on math.SE for details) and the whole $k+16$ bit transmission can be regarded as a codeword polynomial that happens to be a polynomial multiple of the CRC polynomial of degree $16$. Since the data can take on $2^k$ different values, there are $2^k$ different codeword polynomials that might be transmitted, but since there are only $2^{16}$ different $16$-bit patterns of CRC checksums, each $16$-bit CRC checksum is the tail end of $2^{k-16}$ distinct codewords.
The received polynomial is possibly corrupted by transmission errors that change some of the transmitted bits (flipping transmitted $1$'s to received $0$'s or transmitted $0$'s to received $1$'s) and yes, as the OP points out, some of the CRC bits might also be flipped. The receiver does  not care. What the receiver does is check whether the received polynomial is a multiple pf the CRC polynomial (polynomial division of the codeword polynomial by the CRC polynomial again to see if the remainder is $0$). If the received polynomial is indeed a multiple of the CRC polynomial, the $k$ received data bits are accepted as valid, and if not, a re-transmission is usually requested. This follows the maxim of "If at first you don't succeed, try, try again".
In well-designed CRC systems, in most cases, the $k$ accepted received data bits are indeed the same as the $k$ transmitted data bits. But, in a few cases, the accepted $k$ data bits are not the same as the transmitted  $k$ data bits even though the received polynomial has passed the "multiple of CRC polynomial?" test.  This happens exactly when the errors introduced during transmission change the transmitted codeword polynomial (one of $2^k$ possibilities, remember) into another codeword polynomial (another one of the $2^k$ possibilities) that passes the "multiple of CRC polynomial?" test with flying colors, and so the receiver has no way of knowing that it has just bought a pig in a poke. The probability of such an undetected error occurring is quite small.
Example 1:
With $k=1600$, a $16$-bit CRC, and a channel bit error rate of $10^{-4}$, the probability that all $1616$ bits are received without error is $0.9999^{1616} > 0.85$. It takes a minimum of $4$ channel bit errors to flip the transmitted codeword to another codeword, but only very very few of the $\binom{1616}{4}$ error patterns of weight $4$ lead to an undetected error; the vast majority lead to rejection and a request for retransmission. The probability of a specific error pattern of weight $4$ is $(0.9999)^{1612}(0.0001)^{4} \approx 8.5 \times 10^{-17}$, and the probabilities of the higher-weight error patterns that lead to other undetectable errors are even smaller. In short, for a well-designed CRC system, in practice, the probability of an undetected error in an accepted transmission is (acceptably, heh heh) small.
Example 2:
With $k=1600$, a $16$-bit CRC, and a channel bit error rate of $10^{-3}$, the probability that all $1616$ bits are received without error is $0.999^{1616} > 0.198$. Since the number of retransmissions is a geometric random variable with parameter $0.999^{1616}$, on average, it takes 4 re-transmissions to get the codeword accepted. As in Example 1,  the probability of a specific error pattern of weight $4$ is $(0.999)^{1612}(0.001)^{4} \approx 1.99 \times 10^{-13}$, and the probabilities of the higher-weight error patterns that lead to other undetectable errors are even smaller. Indeed, even if we assume that all the undetected errors are equiprobable, the total probability of undetected error is still in the order of $10^{-9}$.  In short, this is still a reasonably well-designed CRC system.
Example 3:
With $k=1600$, a $16$-bit CRC, and a channel bit error rate of $0.2$, the probability that all $1616$ bits are received without error is almost $0$.
This suggests that with such a noisy channel, if we must use a CRC system, we need to use a far far  smaller value for $k$ such as $k=2$ or $k=3$.  Sending $16$ redundant CRC bits to protect $3$ data bits is ridiculous; it would be far simpler and more efficient to just use a repetition code instead!
So what about this stuff about the probability of undetected error with an $r$-bit CRC being $2^{-r}$? Well, as the answer by vml points out, if the received polynomial is just a bunch of random bits (the channel bit error rate is $\frac 12$), then the probability of undetected error is $2^{-r}$. This is such a gross overbound on the actual probability in a more realistic setting as to be essentially useless in practice.
